# java stream map object parameter to hashset

Tags: java, java-stream

Im trying to create a HashSet using the .map and streams functions.

s is an object with an "id" parameter, Long type.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
     HashSet<Long> output = s.stream()
                             .map(v -> v.getId())
                             .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: collect here will return `Set<Long>` so you would have to cast to `HashSet` in your case.

Comment: Further, the `Collectors.toSet` returns a `Set<Long>` which by default uses the `HashSet::new` implementation of the interface which can be found in the implementation of `toSet()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the result of the stream will be `Set<Long>` and you want to assign this to a variable of `HashSet` type. Since `HashSet` is a subtype of `Set` you cannot do this. Either you change the type of your output variable to `Set<Long>` or you explicitly cast the collect result to `HashSet<Long>`. Since `Collectors::toSet` uses `HashMap` by default - it should work.

**EDIT**

As shmosel pointed out correctly it might be a bad idea to make assumptions about the return type so if you want `HashSet` specifically use `toCollection(HashSet::new)` :

```
HashSet<Long> output = s.stream()
                .map(v -> v.getId())
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Now the result of `collect` operation will be `HashSet<Long>` so you will be able to assign it to `HashSet<Long>` or `Set<Long>` variable.